# Android GCM message - how to get preview of the notification

Tags: android, notifications

I'm developing an android app integrating GCM notification capabilities. everything works fine, means I receive the notification (sound + icon on the notification bar) but I would like to display automatically the notification preview on the screen to the end user (when the device is unlocked) for 1 or 2 seconds.

How can I do that ? is there a specific parameter in the notification to permit this preview ?

As soon as the notification is received, I would like to show it to the end user for 2 or 3 seconds and then remains in the notification bar:

[image]

Then, end user can see the notification and the content automatically (a bit intrusive but I just want to know if this is possible)

Comment: can you please show what you mean by `but I would like to display automatically the notification preview on the screen to the end user`

Comment: I would  like the notification displayed on the screen without opening the notification bar (in foreground). I'm trying to find a picture...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is called a [Heads-up Notification](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Heads-up) and can only be done in 5.0+

Comment: Great thanks, and how does lower Android versions will manage such notifications ?

Comment: as I said this ony works on 5.0+, you cannot do this in versions older than that